# How to combine bool must and sort for elasticsearch

Tags: php, sorting, elasticsearch

i am trying to sort some data, where in my base skeleton my sorting is not working and if i remove the sorting it works fine.

So how can i put sorting in my base skeleton and sort some data.

i can't put just

```
   $params['body'] = [           
    'sort' => [['title' => ['order' => 'asc']]]];
$results = $client->search($params);
```

Because i have other condition where i need the must condition.
Can anyone knows how it can be solve.

Any advice will be really appreciate.

```
      // my base skeleton          
      $params = array(
                'index' => "myIndex",
                'type' => "myType",
                'body' => array(
                    'query' => array(
                        'bool' => array(
                            'must' => array(
                            // empty should clause for starters
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                'sort' => array()
                )
            );

     // sorting is not working with bool and must
     if ($request->request->get('salarySort')) {
                $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = array(
                    'sort' => array(
                        "title" => array('order' => 'asc')
                    )
                );
            }
```

this is what i get as a json_encode ---

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1066,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myIndex",
        "_type": "myType",
        "_id": "pe065319de73937aa6ef46413afd7aac26a58a611",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Smarason trycker ",
          "content": "HIF gör 2-0 mot Halmstad.",
          "tag": [
            "Soprts"
          ],
          "category": [
            "Sports"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "0"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "myIndex",
        "_type": "myType",
        "_id": "pebc44a70008f53f74f23ab23f8a1f79b2b729448",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Anders Svenssons tips gav 1-0",
          "content": "Anders Svenssons tips i halvtid Kalmar FF.",
          "source": "Unknown",
          "tag": [
            "Soprts"
          ],
          "category": [
            "Sports"
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          "0"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

query in JSON ---

```
{
  "index": "myIndex",
  "type": "myType",
  "size": 30,
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "match_all": []
    },
    "sort": [
      {
        "title": "asc"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You've correctly placed the empty `sort` array at the same level as your `query`, which is correct.

The issue comes later when you try to feed it as a `bool/must` constraint instead of in the empty `sort` array.

```
 // sorting is not working with bool and must
 if ($request->request->get('salarySort')) {
    $params['body']['sort'][] = array(      <---- this line needs to be changed
        "Salary" => 'asc'                   <---- this line needs to be changed, too
    );
 }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but it is not sorting as it should, can you kindly check it once more, thanks a lot again for your answer :)

Comment: @thanks a lot for your answer val :), although it is not working and not sorting the document :)

Comment: Are you sure your `Salary`  field name is correct? Can you print out the generated query perhaps using `json_encode($params)` or similar?

Comment: i have update my question val, can u kindly have a look :)

Comment: So when i sort by name it is not sorting according to the name

Comment: You've shared the response, can you also share the query as JSON please?

Comment: I HAVE UPDATE MY QUESTION, ACN U KINDLY HAVE A LOKK PLEASE :)

Comment: You're not sorting on the correct field: `name` should be `Name` with uppercase

Comment: if i put "Name" it returns me an error, cause the actual field name is "name"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88167/discussion-between-val-and-christofer-hansen).